# Can I skip parts of the campaign?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

So a while back I started replaying the Age of Empires 3 campaign (nostalgia, y'know). Unfortunately I ended up losing my progress. I was at the beginning of Act II in the original campaign - is there a way to get back there without playing through the entire campaign again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the cheat code of  `this is too hard`, which finishes the current level until you get to Act II.

You can type it in chat in order to activate it.